# Atualização por json não reconhece UTF8 pelo banco de dados

Tags: php

Quando eu aperto no botão CARREGAR no meu portfolio, o $NOME e $TIPO bugam quando tem algum tipo de acento. Os primeiros 6 blocos do portfolio que já são carregados com a pagina, ficam em UTF8 porem os outros não.
Confiram no site:
somospixel.com/test
na parte PORTFOLIO

```
<?php

function fn_conexao(){

    $dbuser = "######";
    $dbpass = "#####";

    try {

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=#####;dbname=#####',  $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $pdo -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
        $pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");//corrige os acentos na hora de gravar no BD
    } catch(Exception $e) {

        echo 'Erro na conexao: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $pdo;
}

function dados($pdo){

    try {   

            if(!isset($_GET['id']) or $_GET['id'] == null){

                $id = 0; //se o GET nao for enviado o for enviado como nullo , a variável ID pega o valor de 0

            }else{

                $id = $_GET['id']; //pega o valor passado via GET
            }

            $arr = array();

            $sql = "ALTER DATABASE pot CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM pot WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $linha = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() >= 1){

                return $linha; //retorna o resultado da query

            }else {

                return 0;

            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {

            print 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $conexao = desconecta($conexao);

        }
}

$conexao = fn_conexao();
$dados = dados($conexao);

$dados = json_encode($dados); //converte o resultado para json

print $dados; //imprime os dados na tela
?>
```

Comment: no head do html coloca: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: dei uma analisada no seu site, e percebi que seus dados já vem com o charset errado do servidor mesmo, logo, o problema não está na hora de mostrar no HTML. Tentei reproduzir seu problema aqui colocando strings acentuadas no meu mysql e fazendo request desses dados, tudo OK... **Talvez** seu problema esteja na hora de enviar os dados pelo servidor HTTP, então o que você precisa fazer é adicionar o charset correto ao Apache (caso esse seja seu servidor HTTP). Vide [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1348521/5953895) e [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10926894/5953895)

Comment: @tayllan eu não entendi como vou fazer para ele enviar com o charset certo

Comment: então @kaiquemix, eu apenas chutei o que poderia resolver seu problema: configurar o Apache para utilizar o charset UTF-8. Mas ao mesmo tempo acho difícil ser esse seu problema, e eu não entendo muito mais disso para poder ajudá-lo :(. No [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1344692/5953895) que comentei ali encima tem um pessoal discutindo sobre como eles consertaram problemas similares, talvez ajude.

Comment: @tayllan estou usando o phpadmin do hostgator para isso..

Comment: hum, hosting service. Eh, não consigo ajudá-lo mais :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

só retirar o

```
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");//corrige os acentos na hora de gravar no BD
```

estáva fazendo a conversão duas vezes, com isso ele bugava